# IIF statement In SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need a Little help creating a if statment for a dataset i am trying to make in SSRS.  I have 2 fields DateOrdered and FirstDate(meaning the date it was first ordered ever)  Now I want 3 outputs  Tier 1, Tier 2,and Tier 3  Depending on the time between DateOrdered and FirstDate
0-24 months Tier 1
25-36 months Tier 2 
37 + Tier 3

Now here is the twist, If anything was First ordered before 1/1/10 I want it the clock to start on 1/1/10  So if something was first ordered on 9/25/09  it would put in in tier 2 even if its over 36 beacause the clock was moved.

Not sure how to create this in the edit expression Data set in SSRS

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then this should be close to what you are after. I did not test this before posting so look over it closely for any syntax errors.

```
=Switch(
  DateDiff("month", IIf(Fields!FirstDate.Value < DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01"), DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01"), Fields!FirstDate.Value), Fields!DateOrdered.Value) <= 24, "Tier 1",
  DateDiff("month", IIf(Fields!FirstDate.Value < DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01"), DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01"), Fields!FirstDate.Value), Fields!DateOrdered.Value) <= 36, "Tier 2",
  True = True, "Tier 3"
)
```